# Is shaking an SSD in a laptop bad?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

While I was upgrading my pre unibody MacBook Pro to an SSD, I couldn't take out one of the screws from the old hard drive since it was chipped, so I ended up using an alternate different sized screw I had to mount the fourth side of the SSD. When I finished mounting everything, I noticed the SSD is able to shake a little more than usual.

I'm wondering if this is bad or not. Could I potentially damage my SSD and laptop because I didn't mount the SSD properly?

Comment: Is shaking a usb key bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solid state drives (SSD) hard drives do not have any moving parts.SSDs have very different structures than a regular disk hard drive.

In simple terms an SSD is like a pen drive (also known as thumb or flash drive), but with more capacity and it usually stays inside your computer.

As a result of not having any moving parts, you don’t have to worry about getting scratches on a metallic platter like you do on a regular hard drive. In fact, with an SSD in your portable computer, your computer can actually function portably, which means you can take your laptop where you want to while it is turned on.

Also, assuming that no other component breaks on your computer, such as your LCD screen, if your computer falls, the system will not be affected.

Comment: Besides the SSD, Do you mean that we can use the laptop upside down, or on a roller coaster, or a 360, and there would be no problems with it?

Comment: @Pacerier - Yes.

Answer (score 6):

Since SSDs should have no moving parts, and as long as it doesn't actually hit against something internally (the inside of the machine),  it should be fine.

Comment: Check also if the connector(s) cannot get loose/disconnect.

Comment: Yeah, that would be annoying, but not damaging, IMHO.

Comment: The data and in rare situations the structure of the file system can be damaged by unexpected disconnection(s). The hardware should not have any problems with this. (I hope the firmware of the SSD is robust enough to keep internal data structures in consistent state all the time.)

Comment: While I haven't seen many laptop ssds the ones I've installed in PCs have the SATA connector with a clip, which in theory shouldn't disconnect by itself.. we all know the differences between theory and practice however.